# How to write System.Xml.Linq.XElement using XmlWriter to a stream

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an `XElement` instance and I wish to write to a stream using `XmlWriter` class. Why? Well, one of the configuration settings defines whether to use binary Xml or not. Based on this setting a suitable `XmlWriter` instance is created - either by `XmlWriter.Create(stream)` or `XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(stream))`.

Anyway, I am trying the following code, but it leaves the stream empty:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
  var xmlReader = new XDocument(xml).CreateReader();
  xmlReader.MoveToContent();
  var xmlWriter = GetXmlWriter(stream);
  xmlWriter.WriteNode(xmlReader, true);
  return stream.ToArray();
}
```

I have checked, `xmlReader` is properly aligned after `MoveToContent` at the root XML element.

I must be doing something wrong, but what?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't shown what GetXmlWriter does... but have you tried just flushing the writer?

```
xmlWriter.Flush();
```

Alternatively, wrap the `XmlWriter` in another `using` statement:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
  var xmlReader = new XDocument(xml).CreateReader();
  xmlReader.MoveToContent();
  using (var xmlWriter = GetXmlWriter(stream))
  {
      xmlWriter.WriteNode(xmlReader, true);
  }
  return stream.ToArray();
}
```

You might want to do the same for the `XmlReader` as well, although in this particular case I don't believe you particularly need to.

Having said all this, I'm not entirely sure why you're using an `XmlReader` at all. Any reason you can't just find the relevant `XElement` and use [`XElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.writeto.aspx)? Or if you're trying to copy the whole document, just use [`XDocument.WriteTo(XmlWriter)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.writeto.aspx)

Comment: That's it. I did not flush the writer. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, Thanks for the comment, I will change my implementation accordingly.